# iOS document.body.scrollTop always 0 in iframe

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe

writing code inside of `iframe` page (not its parent. code must be in the iframe `src` page)

trying to detect scrollTop..

I've tried `document.body.scrollTop` which works in all the other browsers.

In the i-things value is always zero. RIP steve jobs

How do I get scrollTop for scrolling iframe in ipad? They both start with i, why did apple make it so hard? You'd think they would love i-frames and try to brand those too right?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is using window.pageYOffset in the parent container of the iframe and sending it to the iframe with postMessage.

Here my solution:

iframe request for scrollTop->

```
this.sendMessage({'type': "getMarginTop", 'source': selector});
```

container listen the message and respond with -> pageYOffset

```
window.addEventListener('message',  function (e) {
        myiframe.contentWindow.postMessage({"type":"getMarginTop-success", "top": window.pageYOffset}, '*'); 
});
```

iframe listen for messages->

```
window.addEventListener('message',  function (e) {
        if (e.data.type == "getMarginTop-success"){
            //here the scrollTop data e.data.top
        }
}, false);
```

I hope can help someone